# $ \mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta t \wedge \tau} \leq C_1 \int_0^t \mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta s \wedge \tau} ds. $ implies $f(X)=0$ or $X\in M$

Tags: stochastic-analysis

I am self-studying the following material, whose source is https://sayanmuk.github.io/StochasticAnalysisManifolds.pdf

I am stuck at the final step of the following propsotion proof.

> Proposition 1.2.8. Let $X$ be the solution of the extended equation (1.2.3) up to its explosion time $e(X)$ and $X_0 \in M$. Then $X_t \in M$ for $0 \leq t < e(X)$.

> Proof. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $X_0$ is uniformly bounded (see the end of the proof of Theorem 1.1.8). Let $d_{RN}(x, M)$ be the Euclidean distance from $x$ to $M$. Because $M$ is closed and without boundary, the function $f(x) = d_{RN}(x, M)^2$ is smooth in a neighborhood of $M$. Multiplying by a suitable cut-off function, we may assume that $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

> Since the vector fields $V_{\alpha}$ are tangent to $M$ along the submanifold $M$, a local calculation shows that the functions $V_{\alpha}f$ and $V_{\alpha}V_{\beta}f$ vanish along $M$ at a rate proportional to the square of the distance $d_{RN}(x, M)$. Hence, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $M$ such that:

> (i) $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in U$ if and only if $x \in M$;

> (ii) for each $R > 0$, there exists $C$ depending on $R$ such that $|V_{\alpha}f(x)| \leq Cf(x)$, $|V_{\alpha}V_{\beta}f(x)| \leq Cf(x)$ for all $x \in U \cap B(0, R)$.

> Define the stopping times:
> $$
> \tau_R = \inf\{ t > 0 : X_t \notin B(R) \},
> $$
> $$
> \tau_U = \inf\{ t > 0 : X_t \notin U \},
> $$
> $$
> \tau = \tau_U \wedge \tau_R.
> $$

> Consider the process $X$ before $\tau$, the first exit time from $U \cap B(R)$. Applying Itô's formula, we have:
> $$
> f(X_t) = \int_0^t V_{\alpha}f(X_s) dZ_s^{\alpha} + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t V_{\alpha}V_{\beta}f(X_s) d\langle Z^{\alpha}, Z^{\beta} \rangle_s,
> $$
> where $Z^{\beta}$ is.

> Using Lemma 1.1.2 to the right side of the above equation, we have:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta t \wedge \tau} \leq C \sum_{\alpha, \beta} \int_0^{\eta t \wedge \tau} (|V_{\alpha}f(X_s)|^2 + |V_{\alpha}V_{\beta}f(X_s)|^2) ds.
> $$

> We now make the time change $s \mapsto \eta s$ and use (1.2.4), which is permissible because $X_s \in U \cap B(R)$ if $s \leq \tau$. This yields the inequality:
> $$
> \mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta t \wedge \tau} \leq C_1 \int_0^t \mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta s \wedge \tau} ds.
> $$

> It follows that $f(X_s) = 0$ for $s \leq \eta t \wedge \tau$, or $X_s \in M$ for $0 \leq s < \eta t \wedge \tau_U \wedge \tau_R$.

> Letting $t$ and then $R$ go to infinity, we see that $X_s \in M$ for $0 \leq s < e(X) \wedge \tau_U$, from which we conclude easily that $X$ stays on $M$ up to $e(X)$. $\blacksquare$

**Question** How can the author know that f(x)=0 or $X_s\in M$ by looking at $$
\mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta t \wedge \tau} \leq C_1 \int_0^t \mathbb{E}|f(X)|^2_{\infty, \eta s \wedge \tau} ds.
$$?

$C_1$ can be bigger than 1 and so, it does not require $f(x)=0$, at least I do not see how.

Can someone explain me this step?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the definition of explosion time:

> **Definition 1.1.4.**: An $M$-valued path $x$ with explosion time $e = e(x) > 0$ is a continuous map $x : [0,\infty) \to M_c$ such that $x_t \in M$ for $0 \leq t < e$ and $x_t = \partial M$ for all $t \geq e$ if $e < \infty$. The space of $M$-valued paths with explosion time is called the path space of $M$ and is denoted by $W(M)$.

Comment: What is $M$?  Just any subset of the codomain of $X$?  Also, it would probably help to add the definition of $e(X)$.

Comment: @user6247850          $M$ is a manifold and $e(X)$ is the explosion time.

Comment: Yes, I read what $e(X)$ is.  I suggested including the definition of it, i.e. the definition of explosion time.

Comment: @user6247850 I have just included it. Please see my edit.

Comment: Sorry, but why doesn't this proposition follow immediately from the definition of $e$, then?  The proposition is that $X_t \in M$ for $0 \le t < e(X)$, but the first part of the definition of the explosion time is that $x_t \in M$ for $0 \le t < e(x)$.